# TypeError: this.sendHandshake is not a function

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Im trying to create a simple class (wrapper) for a nodejs & socket.io game.

```
module.exports = class client {
constructor(socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
    this.createEvents();
}

createEvents() {
    console.log('creating events');
    this.socket.on('handshake', this.onHandshake);
    this.socket.on('disconnect', this.onDisconnect);
}

sendHandshake() { // <------------ sendHandshake is there?
    console.log('sending handshake');
    this.socket.emit('handshake');
}

onHandshake() {
    console.log('handshake received');
    this.sendHandshake(); // <----- TypeError: this.sendHandshake is not a function
}

onDisconnect() {
    console.log('client disconnected');
}
}
```

it should give me this output

```
creating events
handshake received
sending handshake
```

but instead it gives me this error

```
creating events
handshake received
TypeError: this.sendHandshake is not a function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass a function it is not automatically bound to the object that owns the function. A simpler example would be:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
class client {
    constructor() {
        this.ev = new EventEmitter;
        this.ev.on('handshake', this.onHandshake);
        this.ev.emit('handshake');
    }

    onHandshake() {
        console.log(this); // EventEmitter
    }
}
```

Instead you must bind the function to `client` which you can do pretty easily just by using `this.onHandshake.bind(this)` or `() => this.onHandshake()`. The former binds `this` explicitly. The latter binds `this` lexically, i.e. whatever `this` is in the function where it's defined.

---

I'll also point out that you respond to `handshake` by emitting `handshake` -- not sure if that's intended or needed.